# Postgresql function return integer or null

Tags: postgresql

I have a function like this, which checks for appropriate account type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc_is_exclusive(acc_no integer, acc_type char) RETURNS integer AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE account_no = acc_no AND account_type = acc_type);
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Return type is integer, and if no record found its going to be NULL instead. Does it make sense at all? Or i need to somehow explicitly declare that return type is going to be integer or null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL standard says:

> Every data type includes a special value, called the *null value*, sometimes denoted by the keyword `NULL`.

So it goes without saying that you can return `NULL` as an `integer` result, because `NULL` is a valid value for any data type.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `EXISTS` logic here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc_is_exclusive(acc_no integer, acc_type char) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN EXISTS (SELECT FROM account WHERE account_no = acc_no AND account_type = acc_type);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This would return either true or false, depending on whether or not a matching record can be found.

Comment: But return type would be boolean? Not integer i suppose

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope Yes, you're right, thanks for the correction.